# Append data on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Hi StackOverflow people,

I have a question regarding a small web application that I am currently building.

I have a table of data, in this case phone numbers. I want to apply the phone number when the user clicks on a button next to the number in the table.

1. User clicks on a phone number in table.
2. Phone number gets added/appended to input field .

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards, Casper.

Comment: Provide some code you that you try.

Comment: You wrote 2 ways: "...apply the phone number when the user clicks on a button next to the number..." and "User clicks on a phone number in table.". What of them is correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys, the user will click on the button, then the number will be submitted to the form input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample html assuming I understood the problem right:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1234567890</td><td><button class="btn">Select this</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1111222233</td><td><button class="btn">Select this</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2255667788</td><td><button class="btn">Select this</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" class="phone" />
```

Now for the javascript, something like the following should work:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'),
    phone = document.querySelector('.phone');

// looping through the nodelist and attaching eventlisteners
[].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // fetching the phone number
        var selectedPhone = event.target.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent;
        phone.value = selectedPhone; //setting the value
    }, false);
});
```

Created a fiddle and tested. Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/subhamsaha1004/4f5cX/

Hope this helps.

If the number of rows in the table is more attaching event listeners to every button might not be good idea. The javascript should be changed to attach the listener to the table instead like this:

```
var table = document.querySelector('table'),
    phone = document.querySelector('.phone');

table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // fetching the phone number
    if(event.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'BUTTON') {
        var selectedPhone = event.target.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent;
        phone.value = selectedPhone; //setting the value
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Hey Subham! Your answer was exactly what I needed! However, what if I want to add multiple numbers to the input? (I have currently initialized selectize.js for seperating with tags).

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for the same :

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
$('#inputId').val($('#pnonumberId').val());
});
```

I think you are looking for something like this, let me know if anything else you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.phoneNumer').on('click', function(){
$('#input').attr('value', 'valueToshowInInput');
});
```

Something like this? You need jQuery for this.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JbB4U/

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <input type="text" value="" id="phone">
        <table id="phone-list">
            <tr>
                <td><span class="phone-number">1XXXX-YYYYY</span><button class="click-number">Phone1</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="phone-number">2XXXX-YYYYY</span><button class="click-number">Phone2</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="phone-number">3XXXX-YYYYY</span><button class="click-number">Phone3</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               var $phoneEdit = $("#phone");
               $("#phone-list .click-number").click(function(){
                   $phoneEdit.val($(this).prev("span.phone-number").html());
               });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to the text field and also to the div section where the phone number is, Then use this jQuery code

```
$("#phone-list span.phone-number").click(function(){  

    $( "#phone" ).append($(this).val());

});
```